# Sort a list of abstract objects based on their child's field

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

My abstract object :

```
public abstract class ContentEntry {
    private double score;
}
```

`ContentEntry` has four children, two of them (`Movie` and `Song`) having the field `long date;`

I have a `List<ContentEntry>` that I was previously sorting by `score` with :

```
.flatMap(entries -> Flux.fromIterable(entries)
                        .sort(Comparator.comparing(ContentEntry::getScore))
                        .collectList()
        )
```

I would now like to sort by `date` but I don't see how using Comparator. Thx!

Comment: What behavior are you expecting if the collection has child objects that do not have a date field?

Comment: .... or holds a mixture of child types, some with date fields, some without?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you first have to define how instances of classes *without* the `date` field are compared, and how they compare to objects that have a `data` field.

Once this is done you can define a class

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<ContentEntry> {
  public int compare(ContentEntry e1, ContentEntry e2) {
    long date1 = -1; // Date of first entry, -1 indicates "no date"
    long date2 = -1; // Date of first entry, -1 indicates "no date"
    if ( e1 instanceof Movie ) date1 = ((Movie)e1).date;
    else if ( e1 instanceof Song ) date1 = ((Song)e1).date;
    if ( e2 instanceof Movie ) date2 = ((Movie)e2).date;
    else if ( e2 instanceof Song ) date2 = ((Song)e2).date;

    // Now compare based on date1, date2, and potentially other things
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that it may be better to introduce a function `getSortKey()` that returns the key that is used for sorting. That function could be overridden by classes like `Movie` and `Song`. The could return something that includes the date.